# how to publish my shellscript to dpkg manager

Tags: linux, bash, shell, debian, dpkg

I have shell script code working good. My source is in [github](https://github.com/OmdaMukhtar/LinuxBashHelper). I want to automate preparing the environment, so I decided to make my shell script a package in DPKG.

I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zyRWGzsFdq0) explaining how to build a package  like so :

1. Create a folder for your  package
2. go to that folder and create another folder named DEBIAN
3. now create a "controle" file in that folder
4. write the following details in that file and save

details :

```
Package: // your package name
Version: 1.0.1
Section: base
Periority:optional
Architecture: all
Depends: debconf (>= 0.2.26)
Maintainer: auther_name
Description: hello world
```

and structure my files like this :

```
- mypackage
   -  DEBIAN
       - controle.txt
   - user
     - bin
        - bash02.sh
```

so when I came to compile my `bash02.sh` file in terminal like so :

```
shc -f bash02.sh output bash02
```

it gives my success but it can't run this :

```
bash02 // bash command unknown
```

this my bash script

```sh
#! bin/bash
echo "hello world"
```

so I have two problems :

1. how to run a shell script as I said `shc -f bash02.sh output bash02`?
2. after solve problem one how to publish my package to dpkg manger to be public for everyone to use it?

Comment: Since you published your scripts I'm wondering why you use `shc`at all. As `man shc` states: *"shc's main purpose is to protect your shell scripts from modification or inspection."*. Anyways, did you already try to run `./bash02` or `/please/insert/full/path/to/bash02`?

Comment: @jww thank you, I was using `shc`  because I search how to compile my shell script file on google, and the results say to me use `shc ` to compile my file.

I am using `./bash02 ` while I was in the current path of file `bash02.sh` also doesn't work, it says `bash: ./bash02: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Omda please run pwd, ls and ./bash02 in order and share the output as a screenshot or something.

Answer (score 0):

To distribute your software as Debian package;

> The Path to Take
>
> To integrate a software product with Debian, first you need to package
>   it. You can either do that yourself, or you can ask a Debian developer
>   to do that for you. In either case, you'll end up with a package in
>   DEB format; you can then distribute it yourself or add it to Debian,
>   or both.
>
> If you decide to add your packages to Debian — and I strongly
>   recommend you do that because it is better both for everybody — you
>   have to find out whether they are DFSG-compatible, to post an ITP and
>   to ask a Debian developer to check and upload them.
>
> If you don't add your packages to Debian, and they are many or
>   frequently updated, you might want to set up a package repository to
>   make installing and upgrading easier for your users.

To be accepted to Debian repos, you need to follow Debian Free Software Guidelines (DFSG). You've to be familiar with Debian Social Contract. You need to fill an ITP (Intent to Package). And get a sponsor.

Full read: https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/distribute-deb/distribute-deb.html

Also, this page have some information about contributing to Debian: https://www.debian.org/devel/join/